# Cancelled Transaction in MetaMask USDC leads to loss of funds

Tags: transactions, metamask, contract-invocation, addresses, accounts

I had attempted to transfer 992 USDC from MetaMask to a Ledger Account but had decided to cancel the transaction. On cancelling, MetaMask reports that the cancellation succeeded, but my MetaMask USDC account now says it has 92 USDC. What happened to the 900 USDC? Can anyone tell me what's going on? I am thinking it could be a Meta<ask problem.

Transaction IDs as follows:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd6fa8a8ca403e81730adc0e0757630f9cc23ba7c5968d557e896094911a83756

Copying and pasting the transaction log from Meta<ask as follows:

**Send USDC Details**

From: 0xED3Aa978586ed... > To: 0x95dd8c9653EBAD7...
Transaction
Nonce   4
Amount  -992.570199 USDC
Gas Limit (Units)   21000
Gas Used (Units)    21000
Gas Price (GWEI)    79.2
Total   0.001663 ETH    $2.40 USD

Activity Log

- Transaction created with a value of 0 ETH at 05:10 on 3/1/2021.
- Transaction submitted with gas fee of 0.012 ETH at 05:11 on 3/1/2021.
- Transaction resubmitted with gas fee increased to 0.006 ETH at 10:57 on 3/1/2021
- Transaction cancel attempted with gas fee of 0.002 ETH at 10:58 on 3/1/2021
- Transaction successfully cancelled at 10:58 on 3/1/2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you added liquidity to xSigmaDEX on the transaction before your cancellation.

You can see [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x35dcade9548f1a16cddcfce6d564909b4c3228e31c751cab2bf21b343f9d935e) that you sent 900 USDC to the contract. In return, you received 898.222717188814448179 xSigmaDEX DAI/USDC/USDT LP tokens.

I have never used that DEX, however, you should be able to remove your liquidity by sending those xSigmaDEX DAI/USDC/USDT LP tokens back to the DEX and retrieving your USDC.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for that. I found it. I am bit new in being a liquidity provider and also using ethereum...didn't realise that it could take days to it to transact if the gas fees were low.